# const method in a class returning vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, constants

Say I have this class:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Bag
{
    vector<int*> items;

public:
    void addItem(int* i) 
    { 
        items.push_back(i); 
    }
    const vector<int*> getItems() const
    {
        return items;
    }
};
```

The problem is I want to prevent changes of the values pointed by the pointers in parameter items. But using the vector returning from `getItems` I'm allowed to change the pointed values.

Now, in order to fix that I can declare the parameter items as `vector<const int*>` but then I can't change the values in my class either.
Is there any other way to protect the values but still not using const in the items declarations?

Comment: `std::vector<const int*> getItems() const { return std::vector<const int*>(items.begin(), items.end()); }`

Comment: @KerrekSB this should be an answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for the answer but is this the only way?
I feel like creating a copy is inefficient
also, if I create a copy I have to return by value right?

also, what do you say about the first question?

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing pointers?

Comment: @Jinxed: you were already creating a copy in your original code. If you don't want to make a copy, put that constraint into your question. This has implications on the lifetimes of the various objects that are involved and is semantically different from the current code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As **@KerrekSB** pointed out, you need to *reconstruct* the structure, changing the type of *the element* to a const one:

```
std::vector<const int*> getItems() const { 
    return std::vector<const int*>(items.begin(), items.end());
}
```

Here the constructor of `vector<const int*>` utilizes the implicit conversion from `int*` to `const int*`. You can't just return `items` here, because `vector<T>` is [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Arrays) on T. This directly means that there's no way to convert from `vector<int*>` to `vector<const int*>` just by a type cast.

---

To address your comment:

> Is this the only way? I feel like creating a copy is inefficient.

As for the copy, it copies only the pointer data, so typically 8 bytes per element. For a vector of pointers to larger structures, it's typically negligible, but for a vector of `int`s it indeed is a rather large overhead.

Which brings us to the question: why are you storing pointers in the first place? Simply store `vector<int>`, and then you can just return a `const&` to it.

Comment: Careful with those pointers, when the `Bag` goes oos they'll dangle. `shared_ptr` is much better and avoiding pointers altogether even more.

Comment: The reason I was using pointers is because I wanted later on to use objects that does not have default c'tor

Comment: code may be simplified to `return {items.begin(), items.end()};`

Comment: @Jinxed but `std::vector` supports that already, just `push_back` (or `emplace_back`) when you want to add an item rather than initializing with a size.

Comment: What about returning a constant reference rather than a copy of the vector?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What about "never return referencies to temporaries"? You can't cast the reference for the same reason you can't cast the value.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Pardon my observation, but the vector is a class member, not a temporary in a method.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Hence the second part of my comment - you can't cast the reference to it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid copies and allow read-only access to your `std::vector` elements, you could instead provide functions to get a `const_iterator` into the container:

```
class Bag
{
    vector<int*> items;

public:
    void addItem(int* i) 
    { 
        items.push_back(i); 
    }

    //could just be called begin if that gives the correct idea
    vector<int*>::const_iterator itemsBegin() const
    {
        return std::cbegin(items);
    }

    vector<int*>::const_iterator itemsEnd() const
    {
        return std::cend(items);   
    }
};
```

Then you would loop over the `Bag` contents using that iterator rather than getting out a whole `vector` of items. If you provided `begin` and `end` functions then you could even use range-based for-loops.

Comment: Or, in C++Next, that would simply be a range.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz please, explain.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy probably referring to this [range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) and the [associated standard proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4382.pdf).

Comment: @TartanLlama Well, I've read some article from the author of the range-v3 library where he said that it will not be a part of c++17.

Comment: Maybe C++Next++ then!